# An error occurred while installing autoprefixer-rails (6.2.2). Additionally it say's "autoprefixer-rails requires ruby version >= 2.0. "

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle, failed-installation

Im facing this problem when i'm installing bunder using command "bunlde install"

Initially i tried solving this issue by using following command

> gem install autoprefixer-rails -v '6.2.2'

but again it said "autoprefixer-rails requires ruby version >= 2.0."

when i type

> "ruby -v", **my ruby version shows 2.3.0.**

Next i have tried adding

> ruby '2.3.0' to my gem file, then there was a conflict saying your **ruby version is 1.9.3 but your gem file has 2.3.0**

Need help how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Change your ruby version in the system first. If you using [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) then use following command.

```
rvm use 2.3.0
```

If you don't have it then install it by following command

```
rvm install 2.3.0
```

Delete the Gemfile.lock file and run

```
bundle install
```

Hopefully it will work. Thank you